# Converting an array to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, arrays, observablecollection

In a C# application the following array is used:

```
CProject[] projectArray = this.proxy.getProjectList(username, password);
```

However I need the `projectArray` as a `ObservableCollection<CProject>`. What would be the recommended way to do this? So far I'm using the following statement:

```
ObservableCollection<CProject> projectList = new ObservableCollection<CProject>(projectArray);
```

Would you also use this statement or would you recommend other ways?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Building a new collection from an `IEnumerable` as you did is the way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

IMHO , Building a new collection each time you want to add range of objects is not good rather i would follow below design.

Build a class inheriting from ObservableCollection , so that you can access Items property which is protected and then create a AddRange Method which will add items into it

```
public class MyObObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }

    }
OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add));
}
```